# jsファイルの読み込みについて

Tags: javascript, reactjs

プログラミング学習初心者です。
Create React Appにおいてプロジェクトを作成し，実行しました。
ReactのTutorialに従い，src/index.js，public/index.htmlの2つのファイルを作成しました。
index.htmlファイルはindex.jsファイルをコードのどのように読み込んでいるのか教えていただきたいです。
以下にコードを記載します。

*index.html*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class Square extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <button className="square">
          {/* TODO */}
        </button>
      );
    }
  }
  
  class Board extends React.Component {
    renderSquare(i) {
      return <Square />;
    }
  
    render() {
      const status = 'Next player: X';
  
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="status">{status}</div>
          <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(0)}
            {this.renderSquare(1)}
            {this.renderSquare(2)}
          </div>
          <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(3)}
            {this.renderSquare(4)}
            {this.renderSquare(5)}
          </div>
          <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(6)}
            {this.renderSquare(7)}
            {this.renderSquare(8)}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  class Game extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="game">
          <div className="game-board">
            <Board />
          </div>
          <div className="game-info">
            <div>{/* status */}</div>
            <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  // ========================================
  
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
  root.render(<Game />);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ビルドコマンド`npm run build`を実行して下さい。そうすればbuildフォルダ内にアプリケーションのビルドが生成されます。フォルダ内の`index.html`を見れば`index.js`を読み込む`script`タグが見つかるのでは？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。確かに`build`フォルダ内の`index.html`にて`script`タグが見つかりました。読み込んでいるファイルは`build/static/`にある`main.~.js`というファイルなのですが，このjsファイルに`index.js`の内容が盛り込まれているということでしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

[`npm run eject`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject) を実行して生成される `config/webpack.config.js` を見ると、 [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#usage) で `<script>` タグを挿入しているのが分かるかと思います。

```js
...
    plugins: [
      // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
...
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。指摘された箇所で`<script>`タグが挿入されていることを確認しました。